# FATAL ERROR : main have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I get the following error:

> FATAL ERROR : main have you declared this activity in your
>   AndroidManifest.xml?

I don't know how to declare my activity. This is my **androidmanifest.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.androidhive.slidingmenu"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name="info.androidhive.slidingmenu.speak1"/>
    </application>
<uses-permissions></uses-permissions>
</manifest>
```

Where should I put the declaration of my activity? and this is my **speak1.java** *i've edited my speak1.java

```
package info.androidhive.slidingmenu;    
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class speak1 extends Activity { 
     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.speak1);     
     }
     }
```

Comment: Show full log-cat result

Comment: what are your activities other than the MainActivity?

Comment: `speak1` didn't extend anything. Just extend it with `Activity`.

Comment: Post you full logcat initialy looks everything fine

Answer (score 2):

As in log not  declaring `speak1` Activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`. Add `speak1` Activity in `Manifest` using `activity` attribute :

```
 <activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.slidingmenu.speak1" />
```

**EDIT:**

```
public class speak1 extends Activity { 
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.speak1);     
 }
```

Comment: but, it doesn't work the log cat says
05-15 10:35:58.479: E/AndroidRuntime(533): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-15 10:35:58.479: E/AndroidRuntime(533): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.slidingmenu/info.androidhive.slidingmenu.speak1}: java.lang.ClassCastException: info.androidhive.slidingmenu.speak1 cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
05-15 10:35:58.479: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)

Comment: @SiskaVadilah: Add `<activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.slidingmenu.speak1" />` in log

Comment: @SiskaVadilah: and id still not working then post updated `AndroidManifest.xml` and `PagesFragment$1.onClick` method code

Comment: @SiskaVadilah: What is `speak1` classs is this class extending Activity or it is a Fragment ?

Comment: @SiskaVadilah: instead of making comment please update all code in question

Comment: it still doesn't work
    05-15 11:06:18.280: E/AndroidRuntime(525): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-15 11:06:18.280: E/AndroidRuntime(525): android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {info.androidhive.slidingmenu/info.androidhive.slidingmenu.speak1} did not call through to super.onCreate()
05-15 11:06:18.280: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1922)
05-15 11:06:18.280: E/AndroidRuntime(525):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)

Answer (score 0):

As per your error, you should be declared activity speak1 in manifest file.
Then clean and build your project.

Be sure speat1 extends Activity also.

Answer (score 0):

As seeing your Logcat their is ClassCastException coming.
this means you are casting to something which is not correct.
Casting means changing datatype Like casting int to string or something like this.
you should post your entire code.
Pls check for anything related to casting 
Hope this solve your problem.